# CSS not rendering correctly on iOS 7.x when I use 'vw' metric with Ionic (PhoneGap)

Tags: ios, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm making an app using Ionic Framework, which is based upon PhoneGap.

I'm using 'vw' metric for several properties to make them resizable for all the devices, either iOS or Android. When I run on my browser with the 'ionic serve' option and the iOS Simulator for the 8.1 version I get the expected result, but when I run on iOS 7.1 Simulator, all the - and ONLY the - border related properties don't get rendered.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Viewport units doesn't work well on iOS 7 [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

> Partial support in iOS7 is due to buggy behavior of the "vh" unit.

known issues:

> 1. Chrome does not support viewport units for border widths, column
>      gaps, transform values, box shadows or in calc() until version 34.
> 2. iOS Safari (both 6 and 7) does not support viewport units for border widths, column gaps, transform values, box shadows or in calc().
> 3. iOS 7 Safari sets viewport unit values to 0 if the page has been left and is returned to after 60 seconds.
> 4. Internet Explorer 9 in print-mode interprets vh as pages. 30vh = 30 pages
> 5. iOS 7 Safari recalculates widths set in vh as vw, and heights set in vw as vh, when orientation changes.

More info about the buggy behavior

http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/34-iOS7-Mobile-Safari-And-Viewport-Units.html

And a polyfill https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill

Comment: Great info. Thanks! I used the buggyfill and it worked beautifully. I'd vote up but I don't have enough reputation... :/

Comment: Done! By the way, I just thought of another solution. Your answer works well for me, but I believe it won't work if the app has resizing capabilites, since the buggyfill switches vw with px, right?
In this case you can use vw and em mixed together to achieve a similar result. The em metric is relative to font-size of its parent container, and since the problem is with borders only (for iOS), you can do something like this: `.class { font-size: 2.5vw; border: 1em solid black; }`
Then you can control sizing on font-size property.

Comment: The buggyfill worked great for me.  Even though the question has been voted down, your answer helped, so you get a vote up :-)